# Making jQuery .change() event persistent after widget save

Tags: widgets, jquery, select

I'm creating a custom widget that uses a select element with a bunch of options and a simple jQuery function to trigger the visibility for some `<div>`s below it based on the selection, through a jQuery's `.change()` event.

As you see below, this fails when the widget is saved. If I select another option, it works again.

[image: The event is lost after save, or adding the widget]

Here's the abbreviated code:

*HTML view*

```
<div class="widget-test">
    <div>
        <select id="my-select" name="my-select" class="my-select">
            <option value="0">Select an option</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row one">
        <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
        <input name="option1" class="widefat" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="row two">
        <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
        <input name="option2" class="widefat" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="row three">
        <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
        <input name="option3" class="widefat" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(function () {

        $('body').on('change', '#widgets-right select.my-select', function(){
            $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                    $(".row").not(".one").hide();
                    $(".one").show();
                }
                else if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
                    $(".row").not(".two").hide();
                    $(".two").show();
                }
                else if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
                    $(".row").not(".three").hide();
                    $(".three").show();
                }
                else{
                    $(".row").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I tried attaching the JS function to the `widget-added` and `widget-updated` events, without luck.

Any ideas on **how to make the `<div>` visibility persistent** after saving the widget, based on the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form reloads itself each time you save returning to the initial state where all are shown. What you can do is this:

```
// Getting the value of the selected field
var my_select_value = $('#widgets-right select.my-select').val();

// If there's no value selected, hide everything.
if(my_select_value == 0){
    $('.widget-test .row').hide();
}
// Otherwise, show the specific rows
if(my_select_value == 1){
    $('.widget-test .row').hide();
    $('.widget-test .row.one').show();
}
if(my_select_value == 2){
    $('.widget-test .row').hide();
    $('.widget-test .row.two').show();
}
if(my_select_value == 3){
    $('.widget-test .row').hide();
    $('.widget-test .row.three').show();
}
```

At the initial stage of the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @marcovega ! That worked fine. I just had to enclose this in the `widget-updated` and `widget-added` events.

Comment: Glad it helped out buddy.